# 2000 DC and Terminal Server in-place upgraded to 2003. RDP access is now broken

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

This is the latest:

The Terminal Server and TS Licensing features have been uninstalled from the upgraded server. RDP access is allowed in the Remote tab. (Check out the comments on the first answer for that detail, if necessary.) Still, RDP access is broken.

I found out that the **Terminal Server service in the Services MMC is broken**. First, it still contains the Windows 2000 description. Second, it points to the old Win2k Server executable. It obviously doesn't work.

---

I have a Windows 2000 DC that was running Terminal Services in Application Mode. A couple of weeks back, I ran an in-place upgrade to 2003. The server is now running 2003 R2 Standard.

Since then RDP no longer works. We have no need or desire for this to be a Terminal Server anymore other than Administration Mode.

What I am really trying to accomplish is the following:
**Place the upgraded 2003 server into Remote Desktop for Administration.**

*(Interestingly, the "Licensing" setting within the Terminal Services Configuration MMC is not visible.)*

At the moment, Terminal Services is installed on the server, but licensing is not. We were trashing around trying to resolve this and that's the state we've left the server. I've since discovered that for a typical configuration, neither the Terminal Services nor the Licensing features should be installed.

If anyone has any thoughts, they are appreciated.

Also: This is a production server. I can reboot it, but must do so off-hours.

---

Some new details:

RDP is "broken" in the sense that when any client attempts to initiate a connection to the server, they immediately receive a "This Computer cannot connect to the remote computer" error.

Also: There is no "Remote" tab within the Properties sheet for My Computer.

m

Comment: At this point is there anything in the event logs? What SP is installed?

Comment: I will check as soon as I can.

Comment: The primary error that seems related to Terminal Services is in the System Log: The System Cannot Find the File Specified, which is what happens when you try to start the Service because ... it's looking for pre-Win 2003 Terminal Services executable: C:\WINNT\System32\termsrv.exe

Comment: What SP is installed? Try installing or re-installing SP2 and see if that fixes the issue. I'm thinking it's going to copy the missing file or files that are needed.

Comment: I'm sorry. I neglected to get that for you. It's running Service Pack 2. Is there anything you can tell me about reinstalling SP2? Any gotchas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it in remote administration mode (which is a term that was deprecated in W2K3) then simply uninstall the Terminal Services and Terminal Services Licensing components from the server and from your environmet (if TS Licensing was installed on another server).

Comment: I thought we tried that, but am unsure. It was late. I was drunk. That's my story. I will try this tonight. :-)

Comment: From Add Remove Programs make sure to go into Windows Components to look for both and remove them if they're there. Also, when you say RDP no longer works, what exactly is happening? Is Remote Desktop enabled? Do you have the appropriate users\groups selected for Remote Desktop access?

Comment: RDP no longer works meaning when attempting to connect with a client, you immediately receive a "This computer can't connect to the remote computer" error. As for as I know, I am unable to enable remote desktop as there's no "Remote" tab in the Properties sheet for My Computer.

Comment: Hmm... Here's something from the interwebs: run the following from a command line: regsvr32 remotepg.dll

Comment: Dare to do before I remove features? Responsibility is not yours! ;-) TRIGGER PULLED. The Remote Tab is back and the option is on. (It was on already.)

Comment: So the remote tab is back? If so, have you checked to make sure that it's allowing access to the correct user\group? The domain Administrator user account should be allowed by default. Have you tested it? Does it work?

Comment: The remote tab is back, yes, and the option to allow remote access is on. Also: Domain Admin a member of the Remote Desktop Users AD Group. Anything else? If I try to RDP from another workstation, I get the same immediate "can't connect to the remote computer" error. Remember: I've NOT been able to remove the License feature yet. To do that, I believe I need to reboot which I can't do for a few hours.

Comment: I would hold off then on making any other changes until you've had a chance to reboot and check the results. No sense mucking with too many variables for now.